# Two columns are unique if other column is null

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

[Oracle SQL]

Is it possible to create a unique constraint for two columns (id1, id2) if other column (id3) were null?

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT u_t UNIQUE (id1, id2);
```

If not, what other ways I have to resolve this issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function based unique index. In a `CASE` return a GUID when `id3` is null. If it isn't return the actual value of `id1` or `id2`, respectively.

The only problem is, that the types within the `CASE`'s branches must be compatible. That's why I convert them to characters here. Maybe you can do that differently, depending on the data types `id1` and `id2` are of.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i_t_id3_nn_id1_id2
                    ON t
                       (CASE
                          WHEN id3 IS NULL THEN
                            to_char(id1)
                          ELSE
                            rawtohex(sys_guid())
                        END,
                        CASE
                           WHEN id3 IS NULL THEN
                             to_char(id2)
                           ELSE
                             rawtohex(sys_guid())
                        END);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e0242ac9e62689754eaa354a3f6b176);

The other alternative would be a trigger of course. But the index method, though a bit ugly, might be the more performant one.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. Yes, my data types are Integers for "id1", "id2" and a Date for "id3". In that specific case, use GUID is right?

Comment: @Jcbo: I couldn't get it to work with sequences or `dbms_random.random()` so I used `sys_guid()` as it is unlikely that it produces the same value twice, let alone two equal pairs. But you may find a way to make one of the a fore mentioned work. But be aware, that `dbms_random.random()` may reuse values under certain circumstances, which might cause problems. Using sequences might probably be the most elegant way and efficient way.